# Merge 2 lists of dictionaries by property value in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to merge 2 lists of dictionary objects by one of the properties, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax/filters to do so

```
default_settings:
  - { name: 'setting1', value: 'default value1' }
  - { name: 'setting2', value: 'default value2' }
overrides:
  - { name: 'setting1', value: 'overridden value' }
  - { name: 'setting3', value: 'new value3' }
```

This should result in:

```
result:
  - { name: 'setting1', value: 'overridden value' }
  - { name: 'setting2', value: 'default value2' }
  - { name: 'setting3', value: 'new value3' }
```

I've tried my luck with simply adding them, using combine filter, but those things either only work on dictionaries or lists, but not lists of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Of course after 2 hours of trying and searching and eventually making this post, I managed to get it working in a final little thing I tested. So for those who have the same problem, you can use the groupby filter, combined with a mapped last and mapped combine.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    default_settings:
      - { name: 'setting1', value: 'default value1' }
      - { name: 'setting2', value: 'default value2' }
    overrides:
      - { name: 'setting1', value: 'overridden value' }
      - { name: 'setting3', value: 'new value3' }

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }} = {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ (default_settings + overrides) | groupby('name') | map('last') | map('combine') }}"
```

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'setting1', 'value': 'overridden value'}) => {
    "msg": "setting1 = overridden value"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'setting2', 'value': 'default value2'}) => {
    "msg": "setting2 = default value2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'setting3', 'value': 'new value3'}) => {
    "msg": "setting3 = new value3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert them to dictionaries and combine them:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    default_settings:
      - { name: 'setting1', value: 'default value1' }
      - { name: 'setting2', value: 'default value2' }
    overrides:
      - { name: 'setting1', value: 'overridden value' }
      - { name: 'setting3', value: 'new value3' }
    combined_settings: "{{ [default_settings, overrides] | map('items2dict', key_name='name') | combine }}"
  tasks:
    - name: now you have a dict
      debug:
        msg: "{{ combined_settings }}"

    - name: which you can convert back to a list to iterate over
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ combined_settings | dict2items }}"
```

```
TASK [now you have a dict] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "setting1": "overridden value",
        "setting2": "default value2",
        "setting3": "new value3"
    }
}

TASK [which you can convert back to a list to iterate over] ***********************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'setting1', 'value': 'overridden value'}) => {
    "msg": "setting1: overridden value"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'setting2', 'value': 'default value2'}) => {
    "msg": "setting2: default value2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'setting3', 'value': 'new value3'}) => {
    "msg": "setting3: new value3"
}
```

Comment: FWIW, add `dict2items(key_name='name')` to the pipe to get the expected result.